# Error Parsing Token, SqlCeExpeption

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

Hello this is my first time using SqlCe and i am having a bit of trouble, i keep getting this error when i try to run my program(execute a function).
[image]

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow when i tried googling it but the answers given(such as trailing commas etc.) did not work for me, i still got the same error.

Actually it has been a while since i coded in c#, i've been doing PHP for a while now so i'm not really  certain if i formed my code well.

This the C# code:

```
public string Add()
        {

            using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(db.connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO safe(Url, Pword, Desc, DateAdded) VALUES(@Url, @Pword, @Desc, GETDATE())";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Url", Url));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Pword", Password));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Desc", Desc));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlCeException ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }
            }

            return "Data Has Been Stored!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `Desc` to `[Desc]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC` is a keyword in SQL (`ORDER BY FieldName DESC`). You need to enclose it in `[` and `]`

```
INSERT INTO safe(Url, Pword, [Desc], DateAdded) VALUES(@Url, @Pword, @Desc, GETDATE())
```